# How to redirect to page called before switched to login-required=true

Tags: java, jsf, redirect, seam

I have button that switches me to details of advert. But to see details of advert user needs to be logged. So in pages.xml I defined redirect to login page:

```
<rule if="#{!identity.loggedIn}">
  <redirect view-id="/login.xhtml" />
</rule>
```

I don't know how to redirect user to the advert details after login?

When user is not logged he will be switched from ".../app/advert/3" to ".../app/user". And I don't know how to redirect user to details of the advert. I'm losing information about advert id. 
I tried to define param in pages.xml:

```
<page login-required="false" view-id="/advert/*">
  <rewrite pattern="/advert/{advertId}" />
  <param name="advertId" value="#{contextUser.setadvertId(advertId)}" />...
```

but advertId is not set. Any idea?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added event listeners to components.xml. But I've also defined redirection in pages.xml from login to user view: <navigation from-action="#{identity.login}">
      <rule if="#{identity.loggedIn}">  
        <redirect view-id="/user.xhtml" />
      </rule>

Comment: And I'm wondering if this can cause the problem? But I need to redirect to user account if user choose login option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest way todo it.

http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.3.1.Final/reference/html/security.html#d0e8902

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<rule if="#{!identity.loggedIn}">` from your `pages.xml` file. What you need to do is just mark the advert pages as `login-required="true"` instead:

```
 <page login-required="true" view-id="/advert/*">
   <rewrite pattern="/advert/{advertId}" />
   <param name="advertId" value="#{contextUser.setadvertId(advertId)}" />...
```

When a page is marked as `login-required="true"` and is accessed by an unauthenticated user, Seam automatically emits the `org.jboss.seam.security.notLoggedIn` event and redirects to the view defined in `login-view-id`. The event listener you define intercepts this event and saves the current view and parameters.

When authentication is completed successfully, Seam emits `org.jboss.seam.security.loginSuccessful`, which is again intercepted and handled by redirecting to the previously saved view. If no view is saved (i.e. the user went directly to the login page and thus no `notLoggedIn` event was fired), then the normal navigation rule for the log in action takes place (the user is taken to `/user.xhtml`.

Alternatively, you need to emit the `notLoggedIn` event manually in your navigation rule, but keep in mind that navigation rules are only evaluated *AFTER* an action takes place so you would need to add an `<action/>` element in your page descriptor to trigger the rule evaluation, so something like this:

```
 <page login-required="false" view-id="/advert/*">
   <action execute="#{...}" /> <!-- execute any action to trigger rule evaluation -->
   <navigation>
     <rule if="#{not identity.loggedIn}">
       <!-- raise the event to trigger the capture of the current view -->
       <raise-event type="org.jboss.seam.security.notLoggedIn" />
       <redirect view-id="/login.xhtml" />
     </rule>
   </navigation>
   <rewrite pattern="/advert/{advertId}" />
   <param name="advertId" value="#{contextUser.setadvertId(advertId)}" />...
```